# What is the meaning of the cursor in hscan command redis?

Tags: redis

For [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) I saw the following example

```
hscan name 0 match key*
```

Referencing the docs I saw that the number is cursor. I tried changing the number but never saw different results.

What exactly is the significance of the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HSCAN` iterates over the fields in a Hash data structure. The cursor returned it (and all members of the `SCAN` family), is a number that Redis uses to identify the "position" it stopped at.

You **shouldn't** use random numbers for it. The first time you call `HSCAN`, the cursor you provide should be `0`. Redis' reply consists of two parts - a new cursor and a list of fields. To obtain the next list of fields from `HSCAN` you should provide the cursor (number) that the previous call returned. Repeat this until Redis returns `0` as a cursor - that means that the iteration had finished.

In pseudo Redis Lua, iterating over some Hash would be as follows:

```
local cursor=0
local fields={}

do
  cursor, fields = redis.call('HSCAN', cursor, 'somehashkey')
  -- do something with the fields
while cursor ~= 0
```

Comment: So redis will choose itself how much to iterate over?

Comment: Yes, the cursor is like an index for an array in that sense.

Comment: Is there any doc/blog etc. which can elaborate on why this is present and perhaps more detail about how the amount of material to iterate over is decided?

Comment: I understand that we should not start chat in stackoverflow's comments so this is the last one. Where do I propose that the docs be updated? If acceptable, the link that you have provided can be added. That would take the smallest amount of efforts.

Comment: Redis' docs, like the software itself, are open sourced so to contribute the change just open a PR at the repository: https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc